# Link a non-code directory to TFS

Tags: visual-studio-2010, tfs, solution, checkin

I am using TFS to manage my solution - which one of it's projects contains a dicrectory with some files and more sub-directories (with more files :P). Some of those files are code, some aren't.

The point is I want to make Visual Studio treat this folder as part of the project (and all it's contents) - and upload it to the TFS (for it to be available to anyone who gets latest version of the solution/project). If not as part of the project, part of the solution is also good enough.

This is actually my question - how can it be done?

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can upload it throught source control explorer (part of team explorer) or you can right-click the folder (if not shown make sure you have "Show all files" turned on in solution explorer) and click include in project.

Including in project has one advantage - the contents are downloaded with the solution (when clicked get latest version). If the folder is not included in project but only lies under TFS you have to manually "get latest version" in source control explorer.